# What's the difference between life, health, armour and shield?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch has many sources of health. What do all these terms mean?

- Health
- Life
- Armour
- Shield

Comment: This question has a related [Meta Discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11610/should-we-support-what-does-health-mean)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

- **Health** or *HP* is your total life + shield + armour.
- **Life** is simply a number that represents how much damage you can take before you die.
- **Armour** reduces incoming damage.
- **Shield** self-regenerates over time.

Basically, armour and shield are similar to life, in that they contribute to your overall health, but they come with special attributes. A hero can have a mix of life, armour and shield that makes up their total health pool.

Shield will deplete before armour or life does, and armour will be damaged before life is.

### Armour

**Reduces incoming damage by 5** if the hit was 10 damage or more. If the damage is less than 10 then it is halved.

If a hero has innate armour, such as *D.Va*, then they will regain it through normal sources of healing (health packs, *Mercy*, etc). However, other sources of armour such as *Torbjörn's* armour pack are temporary bonuses and will be depleted from the hero once they run out and you will have to pick up another one.

**For example:**

1. *Winston* has 400 life and 100 armour for a total of 500 HP.
2. *Soldier: 76* shoots a bullet that should deal 15 damage.
3. The bullet hits Winston but because he has armour it only deals 10 damage.
4. Winston has 400 life and 90 armour remaining.

*Tracer* shoots very quickly but each bullet doesn't hit hard. If her bullet does **4 damage**, then armour will reduce it to **2 damage** (halved).

Armour is more effective against smaller firearms such as *Tracer* and less effective against heavy-hitters such as *Pharah* and *Junkrat*.

Heroes such as *D.Va* have lots of innate armour (400 life and 200 armour).

### Shield

**Does not reduce incoming damage**.

After **three seconds** of not taking damage, shield will regenerate at a rate of **25/sec**.

Heroes such as *Zenyatta* have innate shield (50 life + 150 shield). Normal sources of healing will restore both the hero's life and shield.

Other abilities such as *Zarya's* **Projected Barrier**, *Reinhardt's* **Shield** or *Winston's* **Barrier Projector** are not shields in this sense. Instead, they are referred to as **barriers** and usually have their own health pool that is separate from the hero.

Comment: Please feel free to make corrections or suggest improvements in case I got something wrong.

Comment: "Normal sources of healing will not refresh shield" I'm not sure about that.  Health packs may not heal it, but healers seem to.

Comment: In closed beta shields couldn't be healed by healers but the have since changed this. I'm not sure about health packs either by healing characters can definitely restore shields.

Comment: Does Not Reduce Incoming Damage, Adds extra health when Active.    because as it is now it's not immediately obvious how it works.

Comment: How does armor work if your hero does not have sufficient armor to cover all of the damage in a hit? For example, if I have 5 armor left but I get hit by a shot that does 20 damage, do I still only take 15 damage total?

Comment: Healing restores health, so shields and armor are affected, as seen when Mercy heals Bastions, Zaryas, Zenyattas, or Symmetras

Comment: I've never played Overwatch; however, it appears you are italicising hero names (e.g. _Symmetra_, _Zenyetta_). It appears you haven't done this for all instances (e.g. _D. Va_, _Torbjörn_). I'm wondering if this is deliberate or not.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj - I can't verify this in game at the moment, but I believe that the damage mitigation is present so long as you have any armour, and then the damage is subtracted afterwards. So, in your example you'd take 15 damage total from the 20 damage shot. This would subtract 5 armour and 10 life. The next hit you receive would be at full damage since you now have no armour left.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj - I've asked a question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282193/how-does-armour-damage-reduction-interact-with-other-life-types-in-overwatch about this since I'm curious to the mechanics. Not that it'd ever be really *useful* to know this in game, but I like to know these thigns!

Comment: Isn't the damage to life the only damage that helps charge an ultimate for the damager, or is that a rumor? If it is true I think it would be worthwhile to mention.

Comment: Side note: Brigitte's Armor Pack ability heals and also provides **temporary** armor if you didn't need the entire amount it heals for.  Note that it goes away after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

**Overshield / Overheal / Bonus Health**

In addition to the above, the game also has an "Overshield" mechanic, only obtainable from Lucio's "Sound Barrier" as of now.

> Lúcio gives himself and all allies he has line of sight to within 30 meters a large amount of temporary health, which rapidly decays.

[Details](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/L%C3%BAcio#Sound_Barrier) from the wiki: At the time of writing, Sound Barrier grants 500 bonus health which decays over 6 seconds, i.e. losing about 83 of that health every second.

**Order of application**

It's perfectly possible in game to have all 4 of these health types at the same time, so it's worth noting how they interact when you receive damage.

Damage is absorbed in the following order. Once each level is depleted, damage will be applied to the next etc:

1. Overshield
2. Shield
3. Armour
4. Life

If there is not sufficient of one to cover the whole damage for a single hit the remainder will be applied to the next level.

Comment: I could have sworn it was 5 seconds, decaying at 100 per second. Does the wiki include the cast time (the "let's break it down" telegraph) as part of that 6 second window?

Comment: @KizTrap - I'm afraid I don't know, I was just going off the figures on the wiki, which is why I linked it. I'm travelling at the moment and not able to test in-game or I'd check and verify based on the current patch.

Comment: If I get time after tonight's wow raid, I can quickly open a custom match and test this solo. Should be pretty simple :)

Comment: Overshields are now referred to as "Temporary Shields" and are also joined by "Temporary Armor."  Doomfist, Hammond/Wrecking Ball, and Sigma have abilities that give them overshields which (like Lucio's ult) appear as a dark blue color on your health bar by default. Torbjorn can grant himself temporary armor and Brigitte can grant players temporary armor with both her normal heal (if it heals past full) and her ultimate; Temporary armor appears dark orange on your health bar by default.

Comment: This also changes the order that they absorb damage.  As of a recent update it's Temporary Shields, Temporary Armor, Shields, Armor, Health in that order.  Healing order is Health, Armor, Shields in that order; temporary armor and shields cannot be healed.