# Does Winston's Tesla Coil do any damage through armor?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, armor reduces damage taken by 5. Is there a minimum damage or it actually goes to 0?

Lets take Winston for ex. He has:

> Tesla Cannon:
>
> Type:     Multitarget Beam
>
> Damage:   60 per second, **3 per round**
>
> Maximum range     8 meters
>
> Area of effect    6 meter width
>
> Ammo  100
>
> Ammo usage    20 rounds per second
>
> Reload time
>     1.5 seconds
>
> Headshot  ✕

If you check the bolded part you see that he actually does 3 damage per round. That, reduced by armor means -2 (0 since I guess you don't start healing the enemy :)) ) damage. This basically means that any character with 1 armor is unbeatable by Winston. My instinct (and the 99999 kills in Overwatch - although I never checked if the dead ppl had armor or not :P) tells me I'm wrong, but can't find anything to back me up.

Is there maybe a minimum of 1 damage/round or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Armor reduces all incoming damage by half, up to a max of 5. So when Winston attacks someone with armor, he is doing 1.5 damage per round to them until their armor depletes. You can look at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/266839/145980) for more details on how health, armor, and shields work.