# What makes Brigitte Ultimate Armor diferent from normal armor?

Tags: overwatch

As we know from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266840/10647), the different colors on the health bar have different means and mechanics connected to it.

I know that Lucio's Sound Barrier is more blue dark to differentiate it as a temporary shield. But Brigitte's armor is more orange then the yellowish armor that heroes and skills have. So I assumed that is to differentiate the features provided.

So in what is her Armor different from other Armor sources?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This differently coloured armor was introduced at the same time as Brigitte, but it is not exclusive to her; it signifies that the armor is temporary and once removed it can't be recovered just by healing.

In addition to Brigitte's Repair Pack and Rally, Torbjorn's Armor Pack was changed to the same colour when Brigitte was released.

Answer (score 2):

Like Lucio's shield, the armor overheal from Brigitte's Repair Pack is temporary and goes away after 5 seconds. When it goes away, it all disappears at once.  Other than that, it acts like normal armor, which is discussed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266840/87105).

The armor from Brigitte's Rally ultimate acts more like the armor her father, Torbjörn, tosses out in that it lasts until destroyed.

Comment: Correct me whenIm wrong, but isnt it actuallyher ults armor that is in deeper orange, but isnt depleting?